# Watir: can't set textarea content

Tags: ruby, watir

I tried to use `Watir` to go to a link, fill in the keyword, and submit the query. Code below:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.start("https://projectreporter.nih.gov/reporter.cfm")
browser.textarea(id: "p_keywords").set 'keyword'
browser.link(title: "Submit Query").click
```

I can find the textarea, but the `set` command doesn't work.

I also tried `to_subtype.set` as suggested by some other answers but also didn't work.

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of chrome and chromedriver.exe (v65 and 2.37 respectively)?  The behavior you describe sounds like this known (and closed) issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5674.  In any event, I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe.  In future, it is best to include important details like browser, driver, and watir versions.  There are many webdriver issues on SO that are resolved by updating to latest versions.  YMMV.

Comment: Hi orde, Thank you very much for the response. I'm a beginner so apologize in advance if I missed something. The chrome is up-to-date (v65), but I didn't know I need chromedriver. I'm using watir with Ruby on a macbook. Watir version is 6.8.4. I successfully used this set-up for some other (simple) tasks, but obviously don't know enough of the plumbing. I'll check out the chromedriver you mentioned. If you have other suggestsions I can try I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: No need to apologize; we all have to start somewhere.  From terminal, run `which chromedriver`, which will give you the directory where chromedriver is located.  You can find the latest chromedriver here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads.  So, I'd advise downloading the latest chromedriver and replacing the existing one (and you can check the version via terminal with `chromedriver -v`).  `watir 6.8.4` isn't ancient, but the current version is `6.10.3`.

Comment: Hi orde, after updating everything, now it worked! I would've repped you but guess I'm too new to SO and didn't see the option. Thank you very much!!

Comment: nice that it's worked out for you.  I've voted to close this question since it can't be reproduced after upgrading.  Don't take it personal ;)